# Calculate difference between two dates and store in session

Tags: php

I'm trying to calculate difference between two dates and store the result in session then later to use it. The problem is when I show the result it's shows `0`. Here is how I trying:

```
$created = ('y:m:d'); // $created comes from db where the row is DATETIME       

$startTimeStamp = strtotime($created);
$Today=date('y:m:d');

$timeDiff = abs($Today - $startTimeStamp);

$numberDays = $timeDiff/86400;

$numberDays = intval($numberDays);

$_SESSION['created'] = $numberDays;
```

Comment: `$Today` is a string not timestamp. `strtotime($Today)`.

Comment: @b0s3, thank's. Silly me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:
   $created = ('Y:m:d h:i:s'); 
   $startTimeStamp = strtotime($created);
   $date=date('Y:m:d h:i:s');
   $Today=strtotime($date);
   $timeDiff = abs($Today - $startTimeStamp);
   $numberDays = $timeDiff/86400;
   $numberDays = intval($numberDays);
   $_SESSION['created'] = $numberDays;

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
    $datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

Comment: @John Datetime most versatile way of doing this. I suggest you learn it.